# What are some examples of moving a fluid without changing pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Bernoulli's principle states that, in a steady, incompressible, inviscid flow, the sum of all forms of mechanical energy in a fluid along a streamline is the same at all points on that streamline. This requires that the sum of the fluid's kinetic energy, gravitational potential energy, and internal energy (i.e. pressure-volume energy) remains constant.

Real fluids are compressible and have viscosity.

Are there any scenarios that would produce a fluid flow without there being a pressure change? That is, can a fluid flow occur by changing only the fluid's kinetic and/or gravitational potential energy while keeping the fluid's pressure at all points along the flow constant? These questions are open for both the idealized fluid (incompressible, inviscid) and real fluid (compressible, viscous) scenarios.

Comment: Sounds very much like a homework question. But think of rivers, convection in a boiling kettle...

Comment: @planetmaker those are good examples! The convection in a boiling kettle, that would be thermal energy causing the flow, yes? I'm just thinking of the three forms of the mechanical energy Bernoulli considered. Any example of flow caused by a change in kinetic energy alone? (I suppose this is a homework-type question, but not an actual homework problem?, I don't know what constitutes one but I'll add the tag).

Comment: @planetmaker also, I'm wishing now I placed more emphasis on the fluid type when making my question, but I am most interested in learning scenarios where a *gas* flow occurs without a pressure change.

Comment: fluid flow off an inclined plane, dripping of paint off a recently painted wall